# jQuery and $ undefined when sending mvc site to iFrame

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I am setting up an mvc site to be contained within an iFrame on another site(portal) and when the mvc page itself gets rendered, it looks and works fine. When it's loaded inside the iFrame  on the portal site, i get the following errors in IE console and it looks terrible(css) and has no functionality.

'jQuery' is undefined and The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Is there anyway to solve this? I read iFrame's render the content based on the parent code that calls the iFrame which i believe is the problem but wanted to double check on that idea.

Comment: have you double check the jQuery library

Comment: Check your browser's console - it will show you errors. You're not likely loading the jQuery and CSS properly.

Comment: Alright i have found the exact reason why it's not rendering properly in the portal site that contains the iFrame. When i bring up the dev tools in IE, it's loading the page in IE 5 Quirks mode(WTF) which breaks everything. I can manually switch the document mode to IE9 standards and it works flawless!

Comment: The next question is how to force it to use the document mode of the site within the iFrame? I have matched the document types on both the iframe site and the portal site, and included the X-UA-Compatible meta tag. I created an external test html page with only an iframe and the matching document type and it renders just fine, the meta tag works and forces the browser to render properly but it does not when the iFrame on the portal site is used. Ideas?